# Android Scroll to Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, scroll, android-viewpager

**EDIT2**: I'm going to be more clear so everybody understands my question. I hope more people can help me out!

What I made is an app wich contains fragments and tabs to switch between the fragments. I also made it possible to scroll/slide between the fragments using ViewPager.

The only problem now is that the tabs are not scrolling along with the fragments. So when I slide to the last fragment, I can't see the selected tab because it's out of viewingrange.

**How can I make it possible to Scroll to the Tabs when I slide between the fragments?**

I think I have to do something with this part of the code:

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
}
```

But I don't have any clue and everything I tried doesn't work. To make is easier here are two important parts of the code. I hope there's someone that can help me!!

My main code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, MainActivity.TabInfo>();
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    private class TabInfo {
         private String tag;
         TabInfo(String tag, Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) {
             this.tag = tag;
         }
    }

    class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {
        private final Context mContext;

        public TabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs_layout);
        this.initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
        }
        this.intialiseViewPager();
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void intialiseViewPager() {
        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, TabFragment1.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, TabFragment2.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, TabFragment3.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, TabFragment4.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, TabFragment5.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        //
        this.mViewPager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
        this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
        mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        TabInfo tabInfo = null;
        MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Home"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab1", TabFragment1.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Messages"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab2", TabFragment2.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Search"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab3", TabFragment3.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab4").setIndicator("Profile"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab4", TabFragment4.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab5").setIndicator("Settings"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab5", TabFragment5.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    private static void AddTab(MainActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
        tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }

    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
        int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

**WHAT I DID SO FAR CAUSES THE TABS TO DISAPEAR AND REAPEAR WHEN I CLICK THEM:**

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);

    this.hScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView)super.findViewById(R.id.scroller);
    this.hScrollView.scrollTo(((int)(mTabHost.getWidth() * (position / ((double)(mTabHost.getChildCount() - 1))))), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the answer, but [this guy](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) implemented an open source library for what you're doing.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Hmm dificult, It doesn't help me for now but I'm staring to long to this screen. Maybe someone gets an idea.

It has to do something with this part of the code I think:

`public void onPageSelected(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
}`

Comment: Looks like you need to add some code in onPageSelected which tells your HorizontalScrollView that the newly selected tab is out of bounds, and to scroll over to it.

Comment: Prolly something like `mHorzScrollview.smoothScrollTo(((int)(mTabHostWidth * (position / ((double)(mNumTabs - 1)))), 0);`

Comment: Can't get it to work, I'm going to edit my post so maybe more people can help me figure it out. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Do you even know if onPageSelected is getting called when you swipe between fragments? Have you tried a simple `Log.i("TAG", "position: " + position);` in there to make sure?

Comment: Yep it's getting called because when I clear it, the tabs won't get highlighted anymore! So it's defenitely getting called! And the code you gave me yesterday only gives me a lot of errors, I can't even compile it...

Comment: And the log gives me position: 1, 2, 3, 4 etc back!

Comment: Haha, well I just wrote those mXxx variables in there for you to get elsewhere.  For instance, you need to grab mHorzScrollview with a call to findViewById yourself.

Comment: Haha did that and it crashed the app. But i've changed a few things and it's now partially working. What happens now if I scroll around all the tabs disapear. But when I click the bar with the tabs they reapear. Maybe something wrong with the calculation? I've edited the main post! Really thank you for all the help!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it thanks to Josh (see the comments on his answer!). Thank you very much Josh!

It's now working fine, this is the code I used for it:

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    this.hScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView)super.findViewById(R.id.scroller);
    this.hScrollView.scrollTo(((int)(mTabHost.getWidth() * (position / ((double)(4 - 1))))), 0);
}
```

Comment: You should move the findViewById call up to onCreate, so you're not calling it all the time.  Same with mTabHost.getWidth().

Comment: Also, you should mark my answer above as accepted by clicking the green arrow next to it.  And updates like the one you give should be an edit to your original question, not a new answer.  Good luck!